# Ansible error: The offending line appears to be:

Tags: ansible

I am getting code error in Ansible as below. please advise on this.

> ```
> ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, 
> these are the errors we got from each:
> JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>
> Syntax Error while loading YAML.
>   did not find expected key
>
> The error appears to be in '/root/ansible_code/roles/sample_exercise/tasks/main.yml': 
>                            line 10, column 6,
> but may be elsewhere in the file depending 
> on the exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
>     oracle_home: "{{ oracle_home.stdout }}"
>      oracle_sid: "{{ dbname }}"
>      ^ here
> We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
> missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
> start a value. For instance:
>
>     with_items:
>       - {{ foo }}
>
> Should be written as:
>
>     with_items:
>       - "{{ foo }}"
> ```

### Code--

```
#- hosts: localhost
- hosts: 192.168.56.10

- debug:
    msg: "{{ oracle_home.stdout }}"

- set_fact:
    oracle_home: "{{ oracle_home.stdout }}"
     oracle_sid: "{{ dbname }}"

- name: List PDB of given CDB
shell:
 cmd: |
    $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF
    select instance_name, status from v$instance
    EOF
 environment:
        ORACLE_HOME: "{{ oracle_home }}"
        ORACLE_SID: "{{ oracle_sid }}"
 register: pdb

- name: List PDB
 debug:
   msg: "{{ pdb.stdout_lines|replace('\t', '') }}"
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please  use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

> *I am getting code error in Ansible as below. Please advise on this.*

It is just a syntax error caused by incorrect indention. It is reproducible with a minimal example like

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - set_fact:
      oracle_home: 'get_assigned'
       oracle_sid: 'will_cause_syntax_error'
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The error appears to be in '/home/user/test/main.yml': line 9, column 8, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

      oracle_home: 'get_assigned'
       oracle_sid: 'will_cause_syntax_error'
       ^ here
```

The correct syntax would be as follow

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      oracle_home: 'get_assigned'
      oracle_sid: 'also_gets_assigned'
```

Comment: Ok Thank you! Let me try this

Answer (score 1):

As [already answered](https://serverfault.com/a/1136498/37681): your error is most likely syntax error in your playbook.  Meaningful whitespace and sloppy coding/formatting don't mix very well when learning and using Ansible.

Rather than relying on Ansible error messages during playbook execution to find (syntax) errors a better way is to use something like [`ansible-lint`](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-lint-YAML)  before running `ansible-playbook` to check your playbooks and yaml files for syntax errors and common pitfalls.

https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/lint/